# How do I get in the vault in Warframe’s first repair mission?

Tags: warframe

I’m on the first mission in Warframe to repair comms, and I’m stuck on trying to get into this vault:

[image: Screenshot of the vault.]

I’m out of energy at this point from playing around and fear that I’ll have to restart the mission. How do I get beyond this point?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just wasn’t paying attention. You need to hack the console on the opposite side of the vault:

[image: Screenshot of the console.]